# Re-indexing a MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently working on a project with MongoDB. I have 20 million records, which is quite a lot. I query this database with pymongo and do some calculations. The rows are all 'events' from a football game. The problem is that the rows are not ordered the way I want it. The rows are structured by game ( `matchId` ), which is nice, but not by 'event second' (`eventSec`), they do not represent consecutive events. The events of a game are thus mixed together. This is annoying since I would like to be able to jump to a previous and next event when I'm manipulating the data in Python. I know I can query all elements and then sort them in python, but as I'm using 20M records, this takes a lot of time every time I would do this. It is also not very orderly in my MongoDB Compass interface.

My question is: can I re-index my database in such a way that the records are still sorted by `matchId` , and per game, ordered by `eventSec`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index on matchId AND eventSec:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { matchId: 1, eventSec: -1 } );
```

and then query ordering by eventSec:

```
db.collection.find( { matchId: "yourMatchId" }).sort( { eventSec: -1 } );
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Thus there will then be 2 indices, and Mongo will chose the most appropriate index, depending on the query, I suppose?

Comment: If you search sometimes by matchId, and sometimes by matchId AND eventSec, you only need one in this case: the one in my answer.